# John 1:47-49 understanding Nathaniel

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-john

As Nathaniel approaches Jesus the Lord says "here comes a true Israelite in whom there is no duplicity."  Nathaniel asks "how do you know me?"  Jesus answers "I saw you under the fig tree."  Nathaniel responds "you are the Son of God, the king of Israel!"
Why would Nathaniel think Jesus is the Son of God (equal to God) and the King of Israel from the seemingly simple answer "I saw you under the fig tree?"

Comment: I'm new and did not see a way to post an answer to that question.  Help appreciated!

Comment: @JamesRush That particular question is protected against answers by new users - you need 10 reputation to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I had wondered about Nathaniels over the top response for years, it seemed  out of place given what Jesus said.  I read about the significance of fig trees in the Old Testament and understood the fig tree to be a symbol of Israel.  A fig tree with figs was a symbol of prosperity and blessing and a fig tree without fruit was a symbol of judgement and curse.
Not long ago I was attempting to read Rabbi Maimonides' "guide to the perplexed," when I stumbled on the answer concerning Nathaniel.
According Maimonides if an Israelite wanted to express thanks for times of abundance or hope in difficult times one way would be to pray underneath a fig tree.  Praying under a fig tree indicated complete trust in God and specifically God would "see him."  When Jesus said "I saw you under the fig tree," it immediately completed Nathaniels reason for being under the fig tree in the first place.... To be seen as a faithful Israelite by God.